# TestingNG error in Seam project in JBDS

Tags: java, jsf, seam, jboss5.x, testng

I am trying to start a seam project in jboss developer studio 4 GA and following this tutorial: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/GettingStartedGuide/pdf/Getting_Started_Guide.pdf. The simple  seam project runs well until i add the POJO action myAction. The step that says to test the myActionTest.xml file gives and error saying:

> could not connect to
>   RemoteTestNGClient. Make sure you
>   don't have an older version of
>   testng.jar on your classpath

When i run the project the home page runs fine (home.seam) but the myAction.xhtml gives an error saying requested resource is not available:

[image]
[image]

Kindly help me in this matter!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jdk 1.5+, you need to add testng-jdk15.jar in your classpath. Just remember to add this JVM flag when running the TestNG tests:

-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a clean workspace?